# Trying to create a local copy of our google drive with rclone bringing down all the files, constantly hitting rate limits

Tags: google-drive-api, rsync, rclone

As the title states, I'm trying to create a local copy of our entire google drive, we currently are using it as a file storage service which is obviously not the best use-case, but to migrate else where I of course need to get all the files, the entire google drive is around 800gb~.

I am using [rclone](https://rclone.org/) specifically the [copy](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_copy/) command to copy the files FROM google drive TO the local server, however I am constantly running into user Rate Limit errors.

I am using a google service account to authenticate this as well, which I believe should provide more usage limits.

```
2021/11/22 07:39:50 DEBUG : pacer: low level retry 1/10 (error googleapi: Error 403: User 
Rate Limit Exceeded. Rate of requests for user exceed configured project quota. You may 
consider re-evaluating expected per-user traffic to the API and adjust project quota 
limits accordingly. You may monitor aggregate quota usage and adjust limits in the API 
Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/drive.googleapis.com/quotas? 
project=, userRateLimitExceeded)
```

But I don't  really understand since according to my [usage](https://puu.sh/IqKcN/9f476a63e5.png) it is not even coming close, I am just wondering what exactly can I do to either increase my rate limit (even if that means paying) or is there some sort of solution to this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Error 403: User
> Rate Limit Exceeded. Rate of requests for user exceed configured project quota.

User rate limit is the number of requests your user is making per second.  its basically flood protection.  You are flooding the server.  It is unclear how google calculates this, beyond the 100 requests per user per second. If you are getting the error there is really nothing you can do besides slow down your code.  Its also unclear from your question how you are running these requests.

If you could include the code we could see how the requests are being preformed.  How ever as you state you are using something called rclone so there is no way of knowing how that works.

Your only option would be to slow your code down if you have any control over that though this third party application.  If not you may want to contact the owner of the product for direction as to how to fix it.